# How to save the current page in browser's history before sending a Location header in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers, browser-history

I have a page called, for example `page.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php header("Location: https://www.google.com/"?>
```

Now, If I access this page in my browser, it's going to redirect me to `https://www.google.com/`, but the page that I originally visited (`page.php`), isn't going to be saved in my browser history (only Google will be). Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: maybe try with javascript

<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "http://google.com";
}
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">

</body>

Comment: The header takes effect prior to the DOM being loaded, so either your 2nd page needs to inser the history record into the browser (i hate site that do this) or redirect via a client side language such as JS

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://google.com";
 echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Before or after redirecting the user?

Comment: This will redirect user to wherever you want (on example will redirect to google).. and it will be saved on history